# SimpleInjector - how to register many implementations of a generic type with LifetimeScopeLifestyle?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064902/dependency-injection-in-unit-of-work-pattern-using-repositories/16085891#16085891) on SO I couldn't figure out the best technique for registering many implementations of a generic type with an instance of `LifetimeScopeLifestyle` within SimpleInjector.

The recommended method for this form of registration is something like this:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>), 
    typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);
```

But this does not allow an instance of `LifetimeScopeLifestyle` to be passed in.

Below is what I came up with but I know it's not resilient enough as it is checking for any generic interface, not specifically `IRepository<>`. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
public static void Configure(Container container)
{
    var lifetimeScope = new LifetimeScopeLifestyle();

    container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(lifetimeScope);

    //this query needs improvement
    var registrations =
        from type in typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
        where typeof(IRepository).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            && type.IsClass
            && !type.IsAbstract
        from service in type.GetInterfaces()
        where service.IsGenericType
        select new { Service = service, Implementation = type };

    foreach (var registration in registrations)
    {
        container.Register(registration.Service, 
            registration.Implementation, lifetimeScope);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    lifetimeScope, 
    typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);
```

First of all, your query is wrong. It should have been:

```cs
var registrations =
    from type in
        typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where !service.IsAbstract
    where !service.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    from @interface in type.GetInterfaces()
    where @interface.IsGenericType
    where @interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
        typeof(IRepository<>)
    select new { Service = @interface, Impl = type };
```

Second, the framework contains a `GetTypesToRegister` method to fetch these types for you, which excludes decorator types:

```cs
var repositoryTypes =
    OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions.GetTypesToRegister(
        container, typeof(IRepository<>), 
        typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);

var registrations =
    from type in repositoryTypes
    from @interface in type.GetInterfaces()
    where @interface.IsGenericType
    where @interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
        typeof(IRepository<>)
    select new { Service = @interface, Impl = type };
```

But it gets better, the container contains an overload of the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` method that takes a callback delegate that allows you to do the registration as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    (service, impls) =>
    {
        container.Register(service, impls.Single(),
            lifetimeScope);
    }, 
    typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);
```

But most importantly, the framework contains `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` overloads that  takes in an `Lifetime`. So you are able to simplify your registration to the following:

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    lifetimeScope, 
    typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);
```