# Where should I put commonly used data access code with logic not fitting to Repository when using Service classes on top of Repository/UnitOrWork?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

In my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906548/using-the-generic-repository-unit-of-work-pattern-in-large-projects) I was asking about implementing repository/unit of work pattern for large applications built with an ORM framework like EF.

One followup problem I cannot come through right now is where to put codes containing business logic, but still lower-level enough to be used commonly in many other part of the application.

For example here is a few such method:

- Getting all users in one or more roles.
- Getting all cities where a user has privileges within an optional
  region.
- Getting all measure devices of a given device type, within a given
  region for which the current user has privileges.
- Finding a product by code, checking if it's visible and throwing
  exception if not found or not visible.

All of these methods use a UnitOfWork for data access or manipulation, and receive several parameters as in their specification. I think everyone could write a lot more example for such common tasks in a large project. My question is where shall I put tese method implementations? I can see the following options currently.

### Option 1: Every method goes to its own service class

```
public class RegionServices {

  // support DI constructor injection
  public RegionServices(IUnitOfWork work) {...}
  ...
  public IEnumerable<City> GetCitiesForUser(User user, Region region = null) { ... }
  ...
}

public class DeviceServices {
  // support DI constructor injection
  public DeviceServices(IUnitOfWork work) {...}
  ...
  public IEnumerable<Device> GetDevicesForUser(User user, DeviceType type, Region region = null) { ... }
  ...
}
```

What I don't like about it is that if a higher-level application service needs to call for example 3 or these methods, then it needs to instantiate 3 services, and if I use DI then I even have to put all 3 into the constructor, easily resulting quite a bit of code smell.

### Option 2: Creating some kind of Facade for such common data access

```
public class DataAccessHelper {

  // support DI constructor injection
  public DataAccessHelper(IUnitOfWork work) {...}
  ...
  public IEnumerable<City> GetCitiesForUser(User user, Region region = null) { ... }
  public IEnumerable<Device> GetDevicesForUser(User user, DeviceType type, Region region = null) { ... }
  public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersInRoles(params string[] roleIds) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I don't like it because it feels like violating the SRP, but its usage can be much more comfortable however.

### Option 3: Creating extension methods for the Repositories

```
public static class DataAccessExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<City> GetCitiesForUser(this IRepository repo, User user, Region region = null) { ... }
}
```

Here `IRepository` is an interface with generic methods like `Query<T>`, `Save<T>`, etc. I don't like it either because it feels like I want to give business logic to repositories which is not advisable AFAIK. However, it expresses that these methods are common and lower level than service classes, which I like.

Maybe there are other options as well?... Thank you for the help.

Comment: What are you using these methods for? Showing data in views?

Comment: @JefClaes Mostly for other, more complex business logic. For example in a function which synchronizes products - let's say - from an excel file, I woul call a GetProductByCodeOrThrow function. Or for another example, in a service which creates pdf reports, I would call the GetDevicesForUser function. Or it can be even the source of a view, for example I could call GetCitiesForUser and then chain some viewmodel mapping logic after it. A lot of possibilities...

Comment: This is why I wrote "commonly used" phrase in my post, I consider such methods and functions as "low-level business logic".

Comment: How is this business logic, aren't these just queries?

Comment: At the end, in most cases these are queries, yes. Business logic comes while constructing these queries based on parameters, user roles, other application settings, etc. But even if these were just long one-liner queries, I wouldn't like to repeat them in 10 places.

Comment: I think you should think in terms of separating out your application services and your domain services. Here is a post which talks a little on this front https://plus.google.com/110488106924922484445/posts/Erdb9gKkVjG As a side effect you should be able to make your domain services more unit testable. Do have a look at the comments too.

Comment: @Sudarshan Thanks for the comment. I'm quite noob in these topics, but honestly I don't get your point :) I know that these are clearly domain-related services, that's why I would like to separate them. The question is how to implement them to be unit testable, fitting into DI (for unit testing), easily accessible from anywhere in application services, and not violating the DRY principle. If you feel, please post an answer with more concrete implementation details, probably including some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding my conclusion as an answer, because I quickly realized that this question is quite relative and not exact, heavily depends on personal favours or design trends.

The comments and the answers helped me in seeing more clearly how things like this should basically be implemented, thank you for all of your effort.

### Conclusion

A "repository" should be responsible clearly only for data persisting. Because it doesn't hold any domain logic, or type specific logc, I think it can be represented and implemented as an `IRepository` interface with generic methods like `Save<T>`, `Delete<T>`, `Query<T>`, `GetByID<T>`, etc. Please refer to my previous question mentioned in the beginning of my original post.

On the other hand, I think (at least now with my current project) that introducing new  class/classes for each lower-level domain logic (in the most cases some kind of querying logic) task is a bit over-engineered solution, which is not needed for me. I mean I don't want to introduce classes like `GetUsersInRoles` or `GetDevicesInRegionWithType`, etc. I feel I would end up with a lot of classes, and a lot of boilerplate code when refering them.

I decided to implement the 3rd option, adding static query functions as extensions to `IRepository`. It can be nicely separated in a `Queries` project folder, and structured in several static classes each named after the underlying domain model on which it defines operations. For example I've implemented user related queries as follows: in `Queries` folder I've created a `UserQueries.cs` file, in which I have:

```
public static class UserQueries {
  public static IEnumerable<User> GetInRoles(this IRepository repository, params string[] roles) 
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

This way I can easily and comfortable access such methods via extensions on every `IRepository`, the methods are unit-testable and support DI (as they are callable on any `IRepository` implementation). This technique fits best for my current needs.

It can be refactored even further to make it even cleaner. I could introduce "ghost" sealed classes like UserQueriesWrapper and use it to structure the calling code and this way not put every kind of such extensions to IRepository. I mean something like this:

```
// technical class, wraps an IRepository dummily forwarding all members to the wrapped object
public class RepositoryWrapper : IRepository 
{
  internal RepositoryWrapper(IRepository repository) {...}
}

// technical class for holding user related query extensions
public sealed class UserQueriesWrapper : RepositoryWrapper {
  internal UserQueriesWrapper(IRepository repository) : base(repository) {...}  
}

public static class UserQueries {

 public static UserQueriesWrapper Users(this IRepository repository) {
   return new UserQueriesWrapper(repository);
 }

 public static IEnumerable<User> GetInRoles(this UserQueriesWrapper repository, params string[] roles) 
 {
  ...
  }
}

...
// now I can use it with a nicer and cleaner syntax
var users = _repo.Users().GetInRoles("a", "b");
...
```

Thank you for the answers and comments again, and please if there is something I didn't notice or any gotcha with this technique, leave a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that a certain piece of domain logic needs to look at 3 distinct pieces of information in order to make a decision then we will need to provide this information to it.

Further if we say that each of these distinct pieces can be useful to other parts of the domain then each of them will need to be in its own method also. We can debate whether each query needs to be housed in a separate class or not depending on your domain/design.

The point I wanted to make is that there will be a application service which delegates to one or more Finder classes (classes where your queries are housed), these classes house only queries and then accumulate the results and pass it down to a Domain Service as method params.

The domain service acts on on the received parameters executes the logic and returns the result. This way the domain service is easily testable.

psuedo code

```
App Service
result1 = finder.query1()
result2 = finder.query2()
result3= yetanotherfinder.query();
domainresult = domainservice.calculate(result1,result2,result3);
```

Comment: Thank you, am I right if I feel like my third option (extension methods on repositories, aka static pure methods) is the closest to your point? Actually it's still hard for me to interpret your answer and translate it to my concrete scenario. I understand what you mean, but it's too general and theoretic for me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories belong to the domain, queries do not (http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/01/repositories-where-did-we-go-wrong_26.html).

You could define explicit queries and query handlers and use those outside of your domain.

```
public class GetUserStatisticsQuery 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class GetUserStatisticsQueryResult
{
    ...
}

public class GetUserStatisticsQueryHandler : 
    IHandleQuery<GetUserStatisticsQuery, GetUserStatisticsQueryResult> 
{
    public GetUserStatisticsQueryResult Handle(GetUserStatisticsQuery query) 
    {
        ... "SELECT * FROM x" ...
    }
}

var result = _queryExecutor.Execute<GetUserStatisticsQueryResult>(
    new GetUserStatisticsQuery(1));
```

Comment: Thank you, I've read your post, and I can agree with most of it. I'm starting to feel that there is not possible to give an exact, "one fits to all" answer to my question. I have an idea based on the comments and your answers, I will test it soon and give some feedback.