# Register generic types in SimpleInjector Version 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unit-of-work, simple-injector

I've been following the very helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064902/dependency-injection-in-unit-of-work-pattern-using-repositories/16085891#16085891) to organise my unit of work and repositories dynamically using SimpleInjector DI.

Using the test service below:

```
public class TestService
{
    public TestService(IRepository<Call> calls){}       
}
```

In the controller:

```
public class TestingController : Controller
{

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork ;

    public TestingController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, TestService testService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

And the bootstrapper:

```
public static class BootStrapper
{
    public static void ConfigureWeb(Container container)
    {
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
                    container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior = new GreediestConstructorBehavior();


        container.Register<DbContext, OCISContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<ApplicationUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<ApplicationSignInManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(() =>
            AdvancedExtensions.IsVerifying(container)
                ? new OwinContext(new Dictionary<string, object>()).Authentication
                : HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication, Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);
        container.Register<TestService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }
```

I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type TestService failed. The constructor of type TestService contains the parameter with name 'calls' and type `IRepository<Call>` that is not registered. Please ensure `IRepository<Call>` is registered, or change the constructor of TestService. There is, however, a registration for `IEnumerable<IRepository<Call>>`; Did you mean to depend on `IEnumerable<IRepository<Call>>`?

I've also, tried

```
container.RegisterCollection<IRepository>(new [] {typeof(IRepository)});
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IRepository), new[] {typeof(IRepository)});
```

My intention is to get an instance of GenericRepository as this implents IRepository as shown in the answer in the link above.

Comment: Please update your code and add the relevant code that shows why you are registering repositories in the UnitOfWork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message you get is actually pretty clear (or at least, to me):

> Please ensure `IRepository<Call>` is registered, or change the constructor of TestService. There is, however, a registration for `IEnumerable<IRepository<Call>>`; Did you mean to depend on `IEnumerable<IRepository<Call>>`?

In other words, you made the following registration:

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);
```

`RegisterCollection` means that registrations can be resolved as collection. Your `TestService` however depends on `IRepository<Call>` instead of `IEnumerable<IRepository<Call>>`.

Since I think it is unlikely that your application will use multiple implementations for `IRepository<Call>` at the same time, registration of collections is probably not what you want; there is likely a one-to-one mapping between a closed version of the generic `IRepository<T>` interface and an implementation.

So instead, make the registration as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), new[] { typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly });
```

This ensures the one-to-one mapping and will throw an exception in case there accidentally are more implementations for the same closed generic type.

Comment: Great thanks! it appears to have worked, although any idea why the same repository is created more than once, so it tries to register with the UOW a second time, but fails as the key is already present in `private readonly Dictionary<string, IRepository> _repositories;`?

Comment: All good, I added `container.Register<TestCallsRepo>(Lifestyle.Scoped)` at some point but this was the offending code. All works great now, thanks very much Steven.