# register unitofwork in StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

i need to use StructureMap  for register interface .

i need to register unitofwork in StructureMap  .

Definition of unitowork methods in `ApplicationDBContext` . now how can i register unitofwork ?

```
        public static void InitIoC()
    {
        var container = new Container(_ =>
        {
            _.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<ApplicationDBContext>(new ApplicationDBContext());
            _.For<IUser>().Use<EFUserService>();
        });

        // Now, resolve a new object instance of IFoo
        container.GetInstance<IUser>();
    }
```

it not work .

> The type 'DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19f9d7d4cc76b670'.

Comment: The error is rather clear. What are you having trouble with? Also [edit] your question to include all details in *text*, not screenshots.

Comment: @J.Steen how can i register unitofwork ?

Comment: @J.Steen i Edited

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused where to register. You have to register your UnitOfWork where you are registering your repositories.
You can find same problem here.
[Dependency injection in unit of work pattern using repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064902/dependency-injection-in-unit-of-work-pattern-using-repositories/16085891#16085891)