# Mocking UnitOfWork / GenericRepository Implementation

Tags: c#, mocking, unit-of-work

I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064902/dependency-injection-in-unit-of-work-pattern-using-repositories/16085891#16085891) to a similar question, (the below is an implentation of the 2nd answer)

I'm trying to figure out how to test:

```
 public async Task<string> DoWork()
        {
            return await _testRepository.GetAsync(); <-- how do I test here???
        }
```

*Example Class*

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Test.DataAccess.Core;
using Test.DataAccess.Repository;

namespace Test.DataAccess
{
    public class TestManager : ITestManager
    {
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private ITestRepository _testRepository;

        public TestManager(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _testRepository = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<TestRepository>();
        }
        
        public async Task<string> DoWork()
        {
            return await _testRepository.GetAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

Example Repo Link:

[Class Link](https://github.com/DocGreenRob/TestableGenericRepository/blob/98436e4db2ee90890a49d86cff24ae45153da683/Test.DataAccess/TestManager.cs#L20)

[Repo Link](https://github.com/DocGreenRob/TestableGenericRepository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. What are you trying to test? If you need to mock your ITestRepository that is being built by your IUnitOfWork, with NSubstitute you can do something like:

```cs
public class SomeTestClass
{
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var repository = Substitute.For<ITestRepository>();
        var unitOfWork = Substitute.For<IUnitOfWork>();
        unitOfWork.GetRepository<TestRepository>().Returns(repository);
    }
}
```

In that case you`ll mock both repository and uow and make the uow return the mock repo.

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing the same. But I'm about to post a follow up question.